# How to validate the submit form in JavaScript and solve the problem with the code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, form-submit

I've get a problem with submit form on the website. When I try to submit the form there is an error:

[image: the error text]

If I change the method of sending form to action with method POST it works, but I want to solve this problem. I don't know what is wrong. Can you help me?

This is the code of the form

```html
<form id="form-agent" class="ts-form ts-form-email" data-php-path="assets/php/email.php">

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше Имя" required="">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш email" required="">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="form-contact-message" rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Здравствуйте, хочу получить информацию об объекте #156461"></textarea>
</div>


<div class="form-group clearfix mb-0">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="form-contact-submit">Отправить сообщение</button>
</div>

</form>
```

The JS code:

```
$(".ts-form-email [type='submit']").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).html("").append("<span>"+ text +"</span>").prepend("<div class='status'><i class='fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin spinner'></i></div>");
});

$(".ts-form-email .btn[type='submit']").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $button = $(this);
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    var pathToPhp = $(this).closest("form").attr("data-php-path");
    $form.validate ({   
        submitHandler: function() {
            $button.addClass("processing");
            $.post( pathToPhp, $form.serialize(),  function(response) {
                $button.addClass("done").find(".status").append(response).prop("disabled", true);
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

and PHP file:

```
<?php


mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$to = 'axwlow@yandex.ru';
$subject = 'Заявка с сайта';

$name = "";
$email = "";
$phone = "";
$message = "";

if( isset($_POST['name']) ){
$name = $_POST['name'];

$body .= "Name: ";
$body .= $name;
$body .= "\n\n";
}
if( isset($_POST['subject']) ){
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
}
if( isset($_POST['email']) ){
$email = $_POST['email'];

$body .= "";
$body .= "Email: ";
$body .= $email;
$body .= "\n\n";
}
if( isset($_POST['phone']) ){
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$body .= "";
$body .= "Phone: ";
$body .= $phone;
$body .= "\n\n";
}
if( isset($_POST['message']) ){
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body .= "";
$body .= "Message: ";
$body .= $message;
$body .= "\n\n";
}

$headers = 'From: ' .$email . "\r\n";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
mb_send_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
echo '<div class="status-icon valid"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>';
}
else{
echo '<div class="status-icon invalid"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>';
}
```

Comment: Did you add reference to jquery validation plugin (or any other) that you maybe using.

Comment: The issue is on your Javascript side. Could you add a `console.log` after `var $form = $(this).closest("form");` (so `console.log($form);`) to see if the value `$form` is set to anything?

Comment: `w.fn.init [button#form-contact-submit.btn.btn-primary.float-right, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]

0: button#form-contact-submit.btn.btn-primary.float-right

length: 1

prevObject: w.fn.init [document]

__proto__:`

Comment: as I understand it takes the button